# Evaluate ${ \int_{0}^{ 1}{ \int_{0}^{1}{x\max(x^2,y)\,dy} \,dx} }$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

${ \int_{0}^{ 1}{ \int_{0}^{1}{x\max(x^2,y)\,\text{d}y} \,\text{d}x} }$

How would you sketch the graph for this integral?

Comment: $\max (a,b)$ is not $a+b$

Comment: The integrands are correct, but not the integration bounds.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^{x^2}x^3\,\text{d}y+\int_{x^2}^1xy\,\text{d}y\right]\text{d}x
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite by expressing the integrand as $x^3$ where $x^2>y$ and $xy$ where $y>x^2$.

$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2} x^3\,dy\,dx+\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^1 xy\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1x^5\,dx+\int_0^1 x\frac{1-x^4}2\,dx=\frac16+\frac14-\frac1{12}.$$